# Is there any way to save a tableau worksheet table that contains calculations as a standalone datasource?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a worksheet in my tableau workbook that is a table view which contains multiple calculations that I want to save as a datasource that I then can call in another application to do further analysis/calculations (Databricks, Snowflake, etc).

Is there an automated way to do this so I can refresh on a daily or weekly cadence? I am aware of the manual process of export cross_tab as an excel or csv file but I wanted to know if there was an automated process that I can save and set an extract schedule which will then be loaded into Databricks?

Sorry for the open-ended question but appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 1):

A Tableau Prep Builder output step can create either a CSV file, Hyper extract or populate a table in a database. Any program can access a CSV file or database table, and a program that uses the Tableau Hyper API can read from a Hyper extract.

Alternatively, you can save a Tableau data source (either "Add to Saved Data Sources" or "Publish Data Source") - which is the meta data for the data source visible in the left margin data pane, and optionally a extract of the data. Tableau workbooks can access Tableau data sources.